# Loop through linked list in kernel space

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

I'm trying to loop over vma's (referenced by the pointer mm) inside of the [task_struct](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched.h). What I'm doing is trying to print some of the attributes of the struct vm_area_struct (specifically, I'm trying to print vm_start). My issue is that I keep getting a NULL pointer dereference error.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
#include <linux/sched/task_stack.h>

void print_mmap(struct vm_area_struct *mmap)
{ 
        while (mmap != NULL)
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "vm_start: %lu\n", mmap->vm_start);
            mmap = mmap->vm_next;
        }
}



void procs_info_print(void)
{
  struct task_struct *task_list;
  size_t process_counter = 0;
  for_each_process(task_list){
        printk(KERN_INFO "new process\n");
        volatile long state = task_list->state; /* state of the process */
        struct mm_struct *mm = task_list->mm; /* address space of this process */
        struct vm_area_struct *mmap = mm->mmap; /* list of VMAs */
                print_mmap(mmap);

        struct files_struct *files = task_list->files; /* list of open files */
        /* registers */
        unsigned long tasks_ax = task_pt_regs(task_list)->ax;
        unsigned long tasks_bx = task_pt_regs(task_list)->bx;
        unsigned long tasks_cx = task_pt_regs(task_list)->cx;
        unsigned long tasks_dx = task_pt_regs(task_list)->dx;
        unsigned long tasks_ip = task_pt_regs(task_list)->ip; /* program counter */
        unsigned long tasks_sp = task_pt_regs(task_list)->sp;
        unsigned long tasks_bp = task_pt_regs(task_list)->bp;
        unsigned long tasks_si = task_pt_regs(task_list)->si;
        unsigned long tasks_di = task_pt_regs(task_list)->di;
      }
  printk(KERN_INFO "== Number of process: %zu\n", process_counter);
}

static int __init entry(void)
{
  procs_info_print();
  return 0;
}

static void __exit end(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO, "Exiting\n");
}

module_init(entry);
module_exit(end);
```

The error I get is

```
[  139.457092] new process
[  139.457094] vm_start: 94895486087168
[  139.457095] vm_start: 94895489552384
[  139.457096] vm_start: 94895489794048
[  139.457098] vm_start: 94895495430144
[  139.457099] vm_start: 139802326335488
[  139.457100] vm_start: 139802326470656
[  139.457101] vm_start: 139802460553216
[  139.457102] vm_start: 139802460688384
[  139.457103] vm_start: 139802574995456
[  139.457104] vm_start: 139802574999552
[  139.457105] vm_start: 139802583388160
[  139.457106] vm_start: 139802583392256
[  139.457108] vm_start: 139802591780864
[  139.457109] vm_start: 139802593472512
[  139.457110] vm_start: 139802595565568
[  139.457111] vm_start: 139802595569664
[  139.457112] vm_start: 139802595573760
[  139.457113] vm_start: 139802595692544
[  139.457114] vm_start: 139802597785600
[  139.457115] vm_start: 139802597789696
[  139.457116] vm_start: 139802597793792
[  139.457117] vm_start: 139802597875712
[  139.457118] vm_start: 139802599968768
[  139.457119] vm_start: 139802599972864
[  139.457120] vm_start: 139802599976960
[  139.457121] vm_start: 139802600017920
[  139.457123] vm_start: 139802602110976
[  139.457124] vm_start: 139802602115072
[  139.457125] vm_start: 139802602119168
[  139.457126] vm_start: 139802602151936
[  139.457127] vm_start: 139802604244992
[  139.457128] vm_start: 139802604249088
[  139.457129] vm_start: 139802604253184
[  139.457130] vm_start: 139802604670976
[  139.457131] vm_start: 139802606764032
[  139.457132] vm_start: 139802606768128
[  139.457133] vm_start: 139802606784512
[  139.457134] vm_start: 139802606788608
[  139.457135] vm_start: 139802606804992
[  139.457136] vm_start: 139802608898048
[  139.457138] vm_start: 139802608902144
[  139.457139] vm_start: 139802608906240
[  139.457140] vm_start: 139802608922624
[  139.457141] vm_start: 139802611015680
[  139.457142] vm_start: 139802611019776
[  139.457143] vm_start: 139802611023872
[  139.457144] vm_start: 139802611048448
[  139.457145] vm_start: 139802613141504
[  139.457146] vm_start: 139802613145600
[  139.457147] vm_start: 139802613149696
[  139.457148] vm_start: 139802613161984
[  139.457149] vm_start: 139802615255040
[  139.457151] vm_start: 139802615259136
[  139.457152] vm_start: 139802615263232
[  139.457153] vm_start: 139802615721984
[  139.457154] vm_start: 139802617819136
[  139.457155] vm_start: 139802617823232
[  139.457156] vm_start: 139802617827328
[  139.457157] vm_start: 139802617933824
[  139.457158] vm_start: 139802620026880
[  139.457159] vm_start: 139802620030976
[  139.457160] vm_start: 139802620035072
[  139.457161] vm_start: 139802620051456
[  139.457162] vm_start: 139802620162048
[  139.457163] vm_start: 139802622255104
[  139.457164] vm_start: 139802622259200
[  139.457165] vm_start: 139802622263296
[  139.457166] vm_start: 139802622410752
[  139.457168] vm_start: 139802624507904
[  139.457169] vm_start: 139802624512000
[  139.457170] vm_start: 139802624516096
[  139.457171] vm_start: 139802624720896
[  139.457172] vm_start: 139802626813952
[  139.457173] vm_start: 139802626818048
[  139.457174] vm_start: 139802626822144
[  139.457175] vm_start: 139802626846720
[  139.457176] vm_start: 139802628939776
[  139.457177] vm_start: 139802628943872
[  139.457178] vm_start: 139802628947968
[  139.457179] vm_start: 139802630078464
[  139.457180] vm_start: 139802632175616
[  139.457181] vm_start: 139802632183808
[  139.457182] vm_start: 139802632204288
[  139.457183] vm_start: 139802632208384
[  139.457184] vm_start: 139802632224768
[  139.457185] vm_start: 139802634321920
[  139.457187] vm_start: 139802634326016
[  139.457188] vm_start: 139802634330112
[  139.457189] vm_start: 139802634629120
[  139.457190] vm_start: 139802636726272
[  139.457191] vm_start: 139802636730368
[  139.457192] vm_start: 139802636738560
[  139.457193] vm_start: 139802636767232
[  139.457194] vm_start: 139802638860288
[  139.457195] vm_start: 139802638864384
[  139.457196] vm_start: 139802638868480
[  139.457197] vm_start: 139802638929920
[  139.457198] vm_start: 139802641022976
[  139.457199] vm_start: 139802641027072
[  139.457200] vm_start: 139802641031168
[  139.457201] vm_start: 139802641121280
[  139.457203] vm_start: 139802643214336
[  139.457204] vm_start: 139802643218432
[  139.457205] vm_start: 139802643222528
[  139.457600] vm_start: 139802643341312
[  139.457601] vm_start: 139802645438464
[  139.457602] vm_start: 139802645442560
[  139.457604] vm_start: 139802645446656
[  139.457605] vm_start: 139802645487616
[  139.457606] vm_start: 139802645540864
[  139.457607] vm_start: 139802647633920
[  139.457608] vm_start: 139802647638016
[  139.457609] vm_start: 139802647642112
[  139.457610] vm_start: 139802647932928
[  139.457611] vm_start: 139802650030080
[  139.457612] vm_start: 139802650046464
[  139.457613] vm_start: 139802650050560
[  139.457614] vm_start: 139802650054656
[  139.457616] vm_start: 139802650386432
[  139.457617] vm_start: 139802652479488
[  139.457618] vm_start: 139802652487680
[  139.457619] vm_start: 139802652491776
[  139.457620] vm_start: 139802652495872
[  139.457621] vm_start: 139802652647424
[  139.457622] vm_start: 139802654740480
[  139.457623] vm_start: 139802654744576
[  139.457624] vm_start: 139802654748672
[  139.457625] vm_start: 139802654756864
[  139.457626] vm_start: 139802654965760
[  139.457627] vm_start: 139802657058816
[  139.457628] vm_start: 139802657161216
[  139.457629] vm_start: 139802657165312
[  139.457631] vm_start: 139802657193984
[  139.457632] vm_start: 139802659287040
[  139.457633] vm_start: 139802659291136
[  139.457634] vm_start: 139802659295232
[  139.457635] vm_start: 139802661093376
[  139.457636] vm_start: 139802663186432
[  139.457637] vm_start: 139802663751680
[  139.457638] vm_start: 139802663755776
[  139.457639] vm_start: 139802663763968
[  139.457640] vm_start: 139802665758720
[  139.457641] vm_start: 139802667855872
[  139.457642] vm_start: 139802667872256
[  139.457644] vm_start: 139802667880448
[  139.457645] vm_start: 139802667896832
[  139.457646] vm_start: 139802669998080
[  139.457647] vm_start: 139802670153728
[  139.457648] vm_start: 139802670157824
[  139.457649] vm_start: 139802670161920
[  139.457650] vm_start: 140733449646080
[  139.457651] vm_start: 140733451108352
[  139.457652] vm_start: 140733451120640
[  139.457653] new process
[  139.463574] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
[  139.463592] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[  139.463595] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
```

Can anyone help me loop until I reach the end of this linked list without throwing an error?

I've read in the kernel that the vma's are also organized according to a red-black tree. However after checking the code within the kernel I cannot find any information stored within the nodes. It might be a more reliable way to go about traversing the vma's. But now I don't know how to access the data stored in them (supposedly).

Comment: In the loop condition you need to compare with NULL the **iterator** itself, not its `vm_next` field: `while(mmap != NULL)`. See e.g. that code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.6/source/arch/parisc/kernel/cache.c#L524

Comment: @Tsyvarev I made the change you suggested and I still get the error. Could you run the code on your end and see if you don't get the error?

Comment: What's strange is that it seems to complete one process just fine and then it suddenly gets a null pointer reference on the next process.

Comment: Checking iterator for NULL is proper way for iterate over linked list. Probably, some other part of your code is wrong. E.g. "new process" denotes new process to be created, and it **invalidates** the object which you are iterating over.

Comment: I'll post the rest of my code so far to show what I've done. One moment please.

Comment: @Tsyvarev just posted the entirety of my code

Comment: Why do you think that the problem in iteration (`print_mmap`)? It could be that crash is occurred in the `procs_info_print` before it calls `print_mmap` or after that call. Note, that calling `for_each_process` without any protection is wrong, you should call it at least under RCU read section, like [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.6/source/fs/proc/base.c#L1116). Note also that above code uses `task_lock`/`task_unlock` when access fields of the `task_struct`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your advice. I'm going to restructure my program and see if I can make any progress.

Comment: @Tsyvarev following your advice and reference to locking I was able to successfully iterate over the processes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
while(mmap->vm_next != NULL)
```

looks wrong. loop control is off by one and `mmap` might be null. Try this

```
while(mmap != NULL)
```

Some processes (namely zombies) don't have a usable VM pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my code to this suggestion earlier (someone had already suggested this) but it didn't make any difference. I'll update my code in the example to reflect this since it's cleaner anyway.

Comment: @rogerroger69: If I were you I'd start checking if everything is null, say `mm` itself.